# how to show sigma algebra of completion of measure space satisfies a certain property

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have a measure space $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$, where $X$ is a topological space, $\mathcal{A}\supseteq \mathcal{B}(X)$ (the Borel sigma algebra on $X$) and we know that $\mu$ has the following property for all $A\in \mathcal{A}$:

$$\mu(A)=\text{glb}\left\{\mu(U):A\subseteq U, U \text{ open} \right\}.$$

The $\textbf{completion}$ of $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ is the triple $(X, \mathcal{A_\mu}, \bar{\mu})$, where $\mathcal{A}_\mu$ is the collection of all subsets $A\subseteq X$ such that there exists $B, C\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $C\subseteq A \subseteq B$ and $\mu(B-C)=0$ and where $\bar{\mu}(A)=\mu(B)$.

There is also a proposition that states that $A\in \mathcal{A}$ iff $A=B\cup N$, where $B\in \mathcal{A}$ and $N$ is a $\mu$-null set.

I want to show that 
$$\bar{\mu(A)}=\text{glb}\left\{\bar{\mu(U)}:A\subseteq U, U \text{ open} \right\}.$$

Here is what I have so far:

Suppose $A\in \mathcal{A}_\mu$. Let $U\subseteq X$ be any open set such that $A\subseteq U$. Then $\bar{\mu}(A)\leq \bar{\mu}(U)$ and hence,
$$\bar{\mu}(A)\leq \text{glb} \left\{\bar{\mu}(U): A\subseteq U, \, U \text{ open}\right\}. $$

I want to show the inequality holds in the other direction. My idea is to use the fact that $A=B\cup N=B \cup (N\cap B^c)$ and mess around with the glb definition, but I keep reaching a dead end. Could someone help me out? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $\bar \mu(A) = \infty$ there isn't anything to show. Otherwise let $A = B \cup N$ where $B \in \cal A$, $N$ is $\mu$-null, and $\mu(B) < \infty$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. According to the lub property of $\mu$ there exist open sets $U,V$ such that $B \subset U$, $N \subset V$, $\mu(U) \le \mu(B) + \epsilon$, and $\mu(V) \le \epsilon$. Let $G = U \cup V$. Then $A \subset G$ and $$\mu(G) \le \mu(U) + \mu(V) \le \mu(B) + 2\epsilon = \bar \mu(A) + 2\epsilon.$$ Since $G \in \cal A$ you have $\mu(G) = \bar \mu(G)$. Thus
$$\inf\{ \bar \mu(U) : A \subset U, U \text{ open}\} \le \bar \mu(G) \le \mu(A) + 2\epsilon.$$ Now let $\epsilon \to 0^+$.